# Convert nvarchar to date and Get data between two date

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I'm collecting data between two date 01/12/2014 and 31/12/2014 but my sql data type in nvarchar

is my query right?

```
SELECT * from customer where date >= convert(datetime, '01/12/2014', 105) 
AND  date <= convert(datetime, '31/12/2014', 105)
```

Result

```
Msg 242, Level 16, State 3, Line 1
The conversion of a nvarchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.
```

can any one solve this problem...

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : choosing the wrong data type](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/12/bad-habits-to-kick-choosing-the-wrong-data-type) - you should always use the most appropriate data type - that's what they're there for, after all! Fix this problem **first** - use the appropriate data time for a date - like `DATE` or `DATETIME2(n)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

as I know you must separate different parts of a DATE with "-" not with "/" in format 105. here is an example:

```
SELECT convert(datetime, '23-10-2016', 105) -- dd-mm-yyyy
```

so you must rewrite your code as:

```
SELECT * from customer where date >= convert(datetime, '01-12-2014', 105) 
AND  date <= convert(datetime, '31-12-2014', 105)
```

Answer (score 1):

The format your string are in, `'dd/mm/yyyy'` is 103, not 105 (which is `'dd-mm-yyyy'`). So, simply use the correct format:

```
SELECT * 
FROM customer 
WHERE [date] >= CONVERT(datetime, '01/12/2014', 103) 
  AND [date] <= CONVERT(datetime, '31/12/2014', 103)
```

Comment: this is not displayed the result

Answer (score 0):

If your date type is nvarchar why don't you try like this:

```
SELECT * FROM customer 
WHERE date >= '01/12/2014'
AND date <= '31/12/2014'
```

Answer (score 0):

Do we really need to convert?

```
SELECT * FROM DBO.CUSTOMER 
WHERE CAST([date] AS DATE) >= '01/12/2014' AND
CAST([date] AS DATE) <= '31/12/2014'
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use this:
(I think converting to `varchar` is make more sense)

```
SELECT *
FROM customer
WHERE CONVERT(varchar, [date], 103) BETWEEN '01/12/2014' AND '31/12/2014'
```

---

In **Date and Time Styles**; `103` is for with `British/French` standard with century (`yyyy`) like this `dd/mm/yyyy`.